What is the action on $\mathrm{Sp}_2(q^2)$ which makes $\mathrm{Sp}_2(q^2)\colon 2$ a maximal subgroup of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(q)$ for an even power of $q$?
I know that there's a homomorphic embedding of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ into $2\times 2$ matrices over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$. But I cannot determine the action of the semi-direct product of $\mathrm{Sp}_2(q^2) \rtimes \mathcal{C}_2$ it a maximal subgroup of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(q)$ for an even power of $q$. I need to determine how it permutes the conjugacy classes of $\mathrm{Sp}_2(q^2)$.

It's a field automorphism. It acts on a matrix by replacing each of its entries $x$ by $x^q$.  I don't really understand what you mean by "for an even power of $q$".

I thought it might be that one, since it's the generator of $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{q^2}/ \mathbb{F})\cong \mathcal{C}_2$. But I couldn't determine how that could work on a subgroup of $\mathrm{Sp}_4(q)$, since over $\mathbb{F}_q$ raising each entry to the $q$-th power merely fixes them.
What I mean by 'even power' is that the field is characteristic $2$.

Let $F= {\mathbb F}_q$ and  $K={\mathbb F}_{q^2}$. You can embed $K \setminus \{0\}$ into ${\rm GL}(2,F)$ my mapping a primitive element $w$ of $K$ to the companion matrix $M$ of its minimal polynomial $f$ over $F$.
For example, for $q=8$, we can take $f = x^2+tx+t$, where $t=w^9$ (and $t$ has minimal polynomial $x^3+x+1$ over ${\mathbb F}_2$), so we map $w$ to the matrix $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\t&t\end{array}\right)$.
Since $M$ and $M^q$ have the same minimal polynomial, they are conjugate by a matrix $C$. In the example with $q=8$, we can take $C=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\t&1\end{array}\right)$.
The matrix $C$ allows us to define an embedding ${\rm Sp}(n,q^2):2 \to {\rm Sp}(2n,q)$ (for even $n$) by replacing each entry of a matrix in ${\rm Sp}(n,q^2)$  by the $2 \times 2$ matrix over $F$ that represents it (i.e. either $0$ or the appropriate power of $M$), and the element of order $2$ in the complement of ${\rm Sp}(n,q^2):2$ is represented by a block diagonal matrix with $2 \times 2$ blocks equal to $C$, and acts as a field automorphism  on ${\rm Sp}(n,q^2)$.
This all works for any prime power $q$. It does not need to be even.

I agree that this construction gives you a map $Sp(n,q^2):2 \rightarrow GL(2n,q)$. But doesn't the fact that the image is in $Sp(2n,q)$ need a small argument?

Yes I expect it does! In practice it probably does not fix your preferred symplectic form, but it is an easy process computationally to replace it by a conjugate it so that it does.

Say $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ and $b$ is a non-degenerate alternating bilinear form on $V$. Considering $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}q$, you can define an $\mathbb{F}q$-bilinear form $b'$ by $b'(v,w) = \operatorname{Tr}{\mathbb{F}{q^2}/\mathbb{F}_q}(b(v,w))$. This gives an embedding $Sp(n,q^2) < Sp(2n,q)$.

This proof omits showing that $C$ is a symplectic matrix (or, if it does, I don't see how), I'll see if I can provide one in a bit
